# When does a dominant morphism of varieties induce a free extension of coordinate algebras?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, extension-field

Let $\phi : X \to Y$ be a dominant morphism of irreducible varieties over an algebraically closed field $\mathsf{k}$, and for the sake of simplicity, let us assume that $X$ and $Y$ are affine. Then the comorphism $\phi^\sharp : \mathsf{k}[Y] \to \mathsf{k}[X]$ is an injection. This defines a $\mathsf{k}[Y]$-module structure on $\mathsf{k}[X]$.

My question concerns whether we can characterise in terms of $\phi$ the necessary conditions required to make $\mathsf{k}[X]$ free as a $\mathsf{k}[Y]$-module?

Comment: I'm just not sure this is a very well-behaved notion since 'free' is not a local condition. May I ask why you're interested in this notion opposed to, perhaps, the question of whether $\phi^\sharp$ is flat (i.e. $\phi$ is flat)?

Comment: I'm working through chapter 5.1 of Springer's linear algebraic groups in order to prove theorem 5.1.6. In the lemmas to this theorem they are considering a set up where you a dominant morphism of irreducible affine varieties $\phi: X \to Y$ such that $\mathsf{k}[X]$ is generated by a single element $f \in \mathsf{k}[X]$ over the image of $\mathsf{k}[Y]$ under the injection $\phi^\sharp : \mathsf{k}[Y] \to \mathsf{k}[X]$. To simplify things, they consider basic open subsets within $X$ and $Y$ so that the minimum polynomial of $f$ over $\mathsf{k}(Y)[t]$ is contained within $\mathsf{k}[Y][t]$..

Comment: and so that $\mathsf{k}[X]$ is free over $\mathsf{k}[Y]$. I don't understand the relevance of freeness here (I can't see where it is used in the proofs). And I can't see how to understand this geometrically in terms of the map $\phi$.

Comment: I was hoping that there was some geometric interpretation to this freeness. Does the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are affine themselves not sidestep the issue of locality?

Comment: By not being local I mean that there are morphisms $\phi:X\to Y$ which are dominant and are NOT 'free' but for which there is an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $Y$ such that $\phi^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i$ is free. This property of not being able to be checked locally on the source is (usually) an indication that there isn't a great geometric notion at play here. I don't have a copy of Springer on me, so I can't check for you. That said, and I apologize if this suggestion is not appreciated, but have you considered using a book other than Springer? It's a fairly old book written in old and (at least to me)

Comment: confusing language. Have you tried looking at other books, specifically the recent book by Milne on algebraic groups?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thanks for explaining. I've also been finding springer confusing because I can find it to be quite terse on the algebraic geometry. The issue is that it seems to have the best explanation of the construction of quotients of algebraic groups from a classical algebraic geometry perspective. And so naturally I went back to try to work through the algebraic geometry section. I've looked a bit at Milne

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112414/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-adam-higgins).